# How can I access ids from Kivy's ScreneManager and process them through the main app class?

Tags: python, kivy

The Kivy SceneManager is great for loading new scenes but seems to loose the ids coming from the

```
self.root.ids.myid.text
```

component that I am looking for.

Here's the code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

"""Defining Designated Screen Classes and Manager"""
class Main_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        return self.ids
class Inventory_Screen(Screen):
    pass
class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('MyKVFILE.kv')
###############################################
"""Building and Initializing GUI Application"""
class MyApp(App):
    """Building the Application"""
    def build(self):
        return kv
    """Posting Information to the Database"""
    def post_request(self):
        ids = Main_Screen()._finish_init(None)
        ids.submit.text = "Submitting"

        """Initializing Database"""
        db = mysql.connector.connect(user = "********", host = "localhost", password = "***********************", database = "*****")
        c = db.cursor()
        db.commit()

        """Getting Information"""
        item = ids.item.text
        price = ids.price.text
        quality = ids.quality.text

        print(item)
        print(price)
        print(quality)

        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO storage (item, price, quality) VALUES (%(item)s, %(price)s, %(quality)s)", {
            "item": item,
            "price": price,
            "quality": quality
        })
        db.commit()
        db.close()

        ids.submit.text = "Submitted"
```

And here is the kv file

```
Screen_Manager:
    Main_Screen:
    Inventory_Screen:

# Main_Screen Layout
<Main_Screen>:
    name: "MAIN"

    #Layout for the set of TextInputs and Labels
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            #Item Input
            Label:
                text: "Product Item"
                size: "150dp", "50dp"
                pos: "60dp", "520dp"
            TextInput:
                id: item
                hint_text: "Enter Purchased Item"
                size_hint: 1, .5
                pos_hint: { "center_y": .5 }
                multiline: False

            #Price Input
            Label:
                text: "Product Price"
                size: "150dp", "50dp"
                pos: "60dp", "470dp"
            TextInput:
                id: price
                hint_text: "Enter Purchased Price"
                size_hint: 1, .5
                pos_hint: { "center_y": .5 }
                multiline: False

            #Quality Input
            Label:
                text: "Product Quality"
                size: "150dp", "50dp"
                pos: "60dp", "420dp"
            TextInput:
                id: quality
                hint_text: "Enter Purchased Quality"
                multiline: False

        # Submit Button
        Button:
            id: submit
            text: "Submit Inventory"
            font_size: "32dp"
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            size_hint: 1, .33
            pos_hint: { "center_x": .5 }
            on_press: app.post_request() #Function that calls the def post_request in main file

<Inventory_Screen>:
    name: "INVS"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "See Inventory"
            font_size: "32dp"

        Button:
            id: "go_back_btn"
            text: "Add Another Item"
            on_release: #Function to change scene to be added later
```

As you can see, I have tried to access the ids through the
`Main_Screen()._finish_init()` Function but that doesn't work.
And when I use the self.root.ids component, it throws this at me

```
self.root.ids.submit.text = "Submitting"
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

The question is, how can I get information if the ids do not exist or the code just fails to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ids` dictionary is created when the `kv` is loaded, and each `id` in the `kv` is entered into the `ids` dictionary of the base widget of the rule containing the `id`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids). So, in order to access the `submit` `id`, you must use the `ids` of the `Main_Screen` instance. Perhaps like this:

```
ids = self.root.get_screen('MAIN').ids
```

Comment: AAAA, I see, Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe writing `self.ids.submit.text = "Submitting"` instead of `self.root.ids.submit.text = "Submitting"`?